# Delphi - .bpl plugins for application - problem while loading > 1 plugin

Tags: delphi, plugins, bpl, jedi

I'm using [TJvPluginManager](http://help.delphi-jedi.org/unit.php?Id=2903) to build simple application with ability to load .bpl plugins.  I have common interfaces declaration in "uIntfs.pas" file, which is kind of SDK ;)

The problem is, that if I try to load more than one plugin, the app throws an error:

> **Cannot load package 'test2'. It**
>   **contains unit 'uIntfs,' which is also**
>   **contained in package 'test'**

It's quite obvious that BOTH bpls contain that file, however I need to make it work ...

Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put your uIntfs.pas into another BPL, and have your plug-ins both reference that BPL.

You'll have to do that for every unit that's common to both plug-ins.

Comment: I was afraid of that ... it will be quite inconvinient to do so, as I'm changing the SDK a lot ... :/ is there a way for auto-rebuilding the package?

Comment: What I used to do is keep all my packages in a separate project group & do a Build All. With the size of my plug-ins, and the speed of the Delphi compiler, this wasn't too much of an impediment for me, but YMMV  :}